# Make calloc opportunistic

Tags: linux, malloc, glibc, calloc

On linux `malloc` behaves opportunistically, only backing virtual memory by real memory when it is first accessed.  Would it be possible to modify `calloc` so that it also behaves this way (allocating and zeroing pages when they are first accessed)?

Comment: Note that for large chunks, `calloc` on Linux/glibc is already opportunistic (uses the same `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` mmap call, as newly-mmapped pages are promised to read as zeroes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a feature of `malloc()` that makes it "opportunistic". It's a feature of the kernel with which `malloc()` has nothing to do whatsoever.

`malloc()` asks the kernel for a slap of memory everytime it needs more memory to fulfill a request, and it's the kernel that says "Yeah, sure, you have it" everytime without actually supplying memory. It is also the kernel that handles the subsequent page faults by supplying zero'ed memory pages. Note that any memory that the kernel supplies will already be zero'ed out due to safety considerations, so it is equally well suited for `malloc()` and for `calloc()`.

That is, unless the `calloc()` implementation spoils this by unconditionally zeroing out the pages itself (generating the page faults that prompt the kernel to actually supply memory), it will have the same "opportunistic" behavior as `malloc()`.

---

Update:

On my system, the following program successfully allocates 1 TiB (!) on a system with only 2 GiB of memory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    size_t allocationCount = 1024, successfullAllocations = 0;
    char* allocations[allocationCount];
    for(int i = allocationCount; i--; ) {
        if((allocations[i] = calloc(1, 1024*1024*1024))) successfullAllocations++;
    }
    if(successfullAllocations == allocationCount) {
        printf("all %zd allocations were successfull\n", successfullAllocations);
    } else {
        printf("there were %zd failed allocations\n", allocationCount - successfullAllocations);
    }
}
```

I think, its safe to say that at least the `calloc()` implementation on my box behaves "opportunistically".

Comment: "any memory that the kernel supplies will already be zero'ed". That's fine and dandy, but what about memory that is returned to the heap by `free` and then `calloc`ed again?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the kernel usually zeros all memory. What that doesn't explain is that I took an application (which I did not write) and changed calls to `calloc` to `malloc` and it crashed. I'm assuming this is because the allocated memory was not zeroed while the application assumed it would be.

Comment: @n.m. Any memory that has not been returned to the kernel has to be zero'ed by `calloc()` if it is to be used for a new allocation. However, if the `free()` implementation returns memory to the kernel (via `munmap()` or `sbrk()`), a new mapping created via `mmap()` or `sbrk()` will again be zero'ed out by the kernel.

Comment: @chewsocks Requesting memory from the kernel and allocating memory are not the same thing. Memory requested from the kernel is used to back allocations via `malloc()`, but not every `malloc()` call requests memory from the kernel. Since `malloc()` is allowed to reuse memory from previously free'ed allocations, `malloc()` can return memory regions that have not been directly requested from the kernel, and which are not zero'ed consequently. Returning memory to the kernel is usually avoided by `malloc()` implementations to avoid the overhead of the syscalls.

Comment: @cmaster Thank! I understand now how `free()` doesn't always result in zeroed memory. Thanks for your example too. It's very similar to one I gave in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452164/why-does-allocating-large-chunks-of-memory-fail-when-reallocing-small-chunks-doe/29452188#29452188 maybe you could take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

From the related `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` section in [`proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> The amount of memory presently allocated on the system. The committed memory is a sum of all of the memory which has been allocated by processes, even if it has not been "used" by them as of yet. A process which allocates 1GB of memory (using **malloc(3) or similar**), but only touches 300MB of that memory will only show up as using 300MB of memory even if it has the address space allocated for the entire 1GB. This 1GB is memory which has been "committed" to by the VM and can be used at any time by the allocating application. With strict overcommit enabled on the system (mode 2 /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory), allocations which would exceed the CommitLimit (detailed above) will not be permitted. This is useful if one needs to guarantee that processes will not fail due to lack of memory once that memory has been successfully allocated.

Though not explicitly said, I think *similar* here means `calloc` and `realloc`. So `calloc` already behaves opportunistically as `malloc`.

Comment: `calloc` is very different from `malloc`. `calloc` guarantees the memory it returns is initialized to zero. `malloc` does not. Unless you know that `calloc` manages to zero out pages without touching them, or somehow defers zeroing until first access, you should think twice before making such generalizations.