# Why does allocating large chunks of memory fail when reallocing small chunks doesn't

Tags: c++, linux, malloc

This code results in `x` pointing to a chunk of memory 100GB in size.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    auto x = malloc(1);
    for (int i = 1; i< 1024; ++i) x = realloc(x, i*1024ULL*1024*100);
    while (true); // Give us time to check top
}
```

While this code fails allocation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    auto x = malloc(1024ULL*1024*100*1024);
    printf("%llu\n", x);
    while (true); // Give us time to check top
}
```

Comment: How does the second code fail? Is it just that the allocation does not show up in `top`? Anyway, I strongly recommend checking the return values of `malloc()` and `realloc()` to see whether your `malloc()` implementation bailed out for some reason.

Comment: @cmaster I'll edit the question in a minute. But I added a check and `x` is null in the second example. But also, yes, it does not show up in `top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that the memory size of your system is less than the 100 GiB that you are trying to allocate. While Linux does overcommit memory, it still bails out of requests that are way beyond what it can fulfill. That is why the second example fails.

The many small increments of the first example, on the other hand, are way below that threshold. So each one of them succeeds as the kernel knows that you didn't require any of the prior memory yet, so it has no indication that it won't be able to back those 100 additional MiB.

I believe that the threshold for when a memory request from a process fails is relative to the available RAM, and that it can be adjusted (though I don't remember how exactly).

Comment: For the record, I have 16GiB of RAM and 8GiB of swap.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're allocating less memory in the one that succeeds:

```
for (int i = 1; i< 1024; ++i) x = realloc(x, i*1024ULL*1024*100);
```

The last `realloc` is:

```
x = realloc(x, 1023 * (1024ULL*1024*100));
```

As compared to:

```
auto x = malloc(1024 * (1024ULL*100*1024));
```

Maybe that's right where your memory boundary is - the last 100M that broke the camel's back?

Comment: Good guess ;) but I changed it to `i <= 1024` and it still works.